# Compilation Warnings on macOS Big Sur : C++ code compiled with Intel icpc

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, intel

On MacOS Big Sur 11.1, using the following file `intel.make` (that I include after in a `Makefile`), I have to set the following FLAGS :

```
    CXX = icpc -std=c++11 -O3 -xHost
    CXXFLAGS = -Wall -c -qopenmp -mkl=parallel -I${MKLROOT}/include -I/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020/usr/include
    LDFLAGS = -qopenmp -mkl=parallel -L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib -lSystem
    SOURCES = main.cpp TSAF_intel.cpp
    EXECUTABLE = main_intel.exe
```

Everything compiles fine but I have an annoying warning just before the generation of executable :

```
icpc -std=c++11 -O3 -xHost -qopenmp -mkl=parallel -L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib -lSystem main.o TSAF_intel.o -o main_intel.exe
ipo: warning #11012: unable to find -l%s in %s
ipo: warning #11012: unable to find -l%s in %s
ipo: warning #11012: unable to find -l%s in %s
ipo: warning #11012: unable to find -l%s in %s
ipo: warning #11012: unable to find -l%s in %s
```

I don't know where these warnings could come from. How can I get rid of them?

Comment: The warning is telling you that the linker cannot find a library in the specified path. You can start eliminating dependencies one by one to see which flag/library is the issue. I suspect it could be mkl. What version icpc and mkl do you use ?

Comment: @newkid . Thanks for your quick answer, I am using `parallel_studio_xe_2020.2.899  (update 2) 2020` for both `ifort, icc and icpc` on `MacOS Big Sur 11.1`.

Comment: The warnings are not currently documented. If your executable runs as expected you can ignore these warnings. If your executable throws an error of missing symbols that offers more clues.

Comment: I'm also seeing these errors, using Intel 19.0.2.184 on BigSur 11.0.1, with MacOS SDK 11.0. I reduced the command line to this:
`/usr/local/bin/icpc-19.0  -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk foo.cpp.o`

And get exactly 6 copies of the warnings in the original question:
`ipo: warning #11012: unable to find -l%s in %s`

Comment: ...in addition, `-lpthread` and `-ldl` add two of these warnings each.

Comment: @gil_mo . So for the moment, there is nothing to do, only waiting for a new upgrade ...

Comment: @youpilat13 why do you think so? They will "fix" it only if it's "broken". The problem is, we don't know whether it's us or them... :)